Why are Spring boot application yaml values for SSL ignored?
My application is a Spring OAuth2 client using keycloak as the OAuth Security server.  When I configure the application to  use SSL, it fails to connect to the open-id configuration endpoint.  I can successfully connect to the URL in a browser outside the app/IDE.
After some debugging I think it is because it is reading the default truststore from the IDE instead of the one configured in my application.yaml.
Any suggestions on what is causing it to ignore the values in application.yaml?
Thanks for taking time to read and think about my question!
The errors
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "https://localhost:8443/realms/MyRealm/.well-known/openid-configuration": PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target 
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

application.yaml
server:
    port: 9443
    ssl:
        key-store-type: PKCS12
        key-store-password: ${self.signed.password}
        key-alias: tim-asus
        key-store: classpath:keystore/self_signed.p12
        enabled: true

My command line includes -Djavax.net.debug=all
Debug output
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|22|restartedMain|2024-05-28 17:18:28.070 CDT|TrustStoreManager.java:113|trustStore is: C:\Users\me\.jdks\temurin-21.0.2\lib\security\cacerts
trustStore type is: pkcs12


The issue you face is most probably due to the fact that the certificate used by Keycloak is not registered in the cacerts file of the JRE your Spring application runs into.
What you configure your Spring app with is not important, what really matters here is the Java runtime configuration (and Keycloak's one).
So the reason why Spring Boot properties for SSL are ignored is that these properties are used for serving content from a Spring application, and here you are consuming data from Keycloak.
The error you face is thrown at a very low level: sun.security, the Java runtime core security layer (below Spring layers). Using the same certificate on Keycloak and in your Spring app won't add this certificate to the Java runtime.
P.S.
To help generate self-signed certificate and add it to the cacerts of each of the JDKs / JREs on your machine, you might find this script of mine useful.

Thanks.  That fixed the "symptoms", the program now runs.  I still don't understand why the application.yaml properties are not effective.  All of the articles I've seen on how to enable SSL only show creating a self-signed cert and adding pointers in the application.yaml.  I do use your script but the IDE JDK wasn't one I targeted for modification.

The articles you are referring to might explain "how to enable SSL in a Spring application" and not "how to connect a Java application (not necessarily Spring) to a server (not necessarily Java) with a self-signed certificate". Updated the answer.

As always, your explanation really helps increase my understanding!
